# ColorConverter ConvertFromString returns wrong name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to convert a hex value to its corresponding color name, but the ColorConverter's ConvertFromString method is inserting extra characters:

```
string s1 = "#000000";
string s2 = "#ccff33";
string s3 = "#990000";
Color color;
ColorConverter converter = new ColorConverter();

color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString(s1);
Console.Write(color.Name); // Outputs "Black"

color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString(s2);
Console.Write(color.Name); // Outputs "ffccff33";

color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString(s3);
Console.Write(color.Name); // Outputs "ff990000";
```

The extra "ff" inexplicably happens for every color but Black and White. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That's because the Color consists of A, R, G and B components. The A component is set to FF unless specified differently.

Comment: Also worth noting that it will happen for every color *but those that have a named value.*  "#ff0000" should give you "Red", for example.

Comment: The additional "ff" is the alpha value, showing the transparency of the color (where ff is solid and 00 would be fully transparent). Maybe the colors you provide don't match named colors. Have you tried to convert #ff0000? Does it return "Red"?

Comment: Aha. Yes, "ff0000" returns red. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have similar functionality in one of our projects, you could use the following

```
(color)ColorTranslator.FromHtml(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ColorTranslator.FromHtml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

That's because `System.Drawing.Color` stores color in ARGB format, which is Alpha + RGB.

To print out just the RGB values:

```
Console.Write(color.Name.Substring(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra "ff" represent the opacity of the color which in this case is 100% (as davenewza said).

A color in Hexa has 2 optional characters at the beginning for the Alpha or opacity, 2 chars for Red, 2 chars for Green and 2 more for Blue (# FF CC FF 33)